# How to use a different partition in Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, partitioning, hard-drive, devices

I had partitioned my Hard Disk when I was installing Ubuntu 12.04, I made two partitions one of 80GB and another one of 140GB. But for some reason by default it only uses sda1 as show in this [Snapshot](http://mkshantilal.blogspot.co.uk/2012/11/blog-post.html).

I have installed VirtualBox and running Windows_XP and I am willing to use sda5 the other partition.

Any ideas how can I do this. Any help will be appreciated

Regards

Comment: You are using both the partitions. All your personal settings and files including the virtual disk etc. for VirtualBox are in `/home/[user name]` and that resides in sda5.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually using both partitions.

`/dev/sda5` is mounted as `/home` it's your personal home for everything. Your VirtualBox VMs by default are stored in `~/VirtualBox VMs` this is on your /home filesystem;-) VirtualBox binaries and config files are spread into `/usr` `/etc`.

If you run `dpkg -L virtualbox-4.2` you'll see the list.

`/dev/sda1` is mounted as `/` root.

So, nothing to worry about.

Comment: So what happens when my sda5 gets full or something?

Comment: Several workarounds: 1. mv your VMs to a different partition, for example a folder on / (/dev/sda1) => /opt 2. Add more spaces, use a new block device (partition) and mount it under /home, for example: /home/storage 3. If you are using LVM or Btrfs it's more flexible to add PV and device to existing storage pool.

Comment: Man I am a little new to this, if you could elaborate it a little please. How can I perform action 1? The last thing I want to do is to reinstall Linux and then do the partitioning and all (which will take time and again I will have to go through the cumbersome process of install perl modules and all that)

Comment: Option 1 is easy, for example move to /opt/VMs and it's done. Because / is a separate partition from /home. Moving your /home/username/VirtualBox VMs to /opt/VirtualBox VMs will free up space on /home and make use of /dev/sda1 (used by /)

Comment: Man I moved it but now my Virtual WindowsXP is inaccessible. I'll have to reinstall it again